# htaccess+modrewrite issue 2

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want that every user has a profile-url like this:

```
www.example.com/username
```

But my php page need the id of the user ( not username ).
for example I want that this url:

```
www.example.com/profile.php?id=13
```

become:

```
www.example.com/john
```

what I have to write in the htaccess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic answer to this question. You obviously need to have a PHP script that is able to take a username as a query parameter:

```
www.example.com/profile.php?username=john
```

Then you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The above rewrite rule will match any string not containing a dot, this may or may not fit your needs, depending on your overall url structure.

Answer (score 2):

> what I have to write in the htaccess ?

This is not a job for the .htaccess file, but for the `profile.php` where you load the actual ID. Change that page so it can accept the user name, and load the correct record.